# failed to run test with gradle in IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

When I click the run button(near the line number) in test file within IntelliJ IDEA. It always run it with Junit not gradle.
Even through I have set the **Preferences->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle->Run test using** to gradle

How to change it to run with gradle?

Comment: Please try to remove existing test run configuration and click button again.

Comment: Not working. still junit

Comment: Is it reproducible with new sample project?